# hazelcast error "Transaction log cannot be found"

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast 3.12.6 with 3 HC instances. After a while I can see this in the logs:

```
2020-04-30 14:27:52 318 WARN  c.h.collection.impl.set.SetContainer:49 - [192.168.0.12]:5701 [xyz] [3.12.6] Transaction log cannot be found for committing 'remove()' operation on backup member. Missing log item ID:661
2020-04-30 14:27:52 361 WARN  c.h.collection.impl.set.SetContainer:49 - [192.168.0.12]:5701 [xyz] [3.12.6] Transaction log cannot be found for committing 'remove()' operation on backup member. Missing log item ID:664
2020-04-30 14:27:52 401 WARN  c.h.collection.impl.set.SetContainer:49 - [192.168.0.12]:5701 [xyz] [3.12.6] Transaction log cannot be found for committing 'remove()' operation on backup member. Missing log item ID:664
2020-04-30 14:27:52 437 WARN  c.h.collection.impl.set.SetContainer:49 - [192.168.0.12]:5701 [xyz] [3.12.6] Transaction log cannot be found for committing 'remove()' operation on backup member. Missing log item ID:664
2020-04-30 14:27:52 606 WARN  c.h.collection.impl.set.SetContainer:49 - [192.168.0.12]:5701 [xyz] [3.12.6] Transaction log cannot be found for committing 'remove()' operation on backup member. Missing log item ID:664
2020-04-30 14:27:52 721 WARN  c.h.collection.impl.set.SetContainer:49 - [192.168.0.12]:5701 [xyz] [3.12.6] Transaction log cannot be found for committing 'remove()' operation on backup member. Missing log item ID:658
```

Is this a severe issue? Am I doing anything wrong? Maybe it is just "nice to know" and normal with HC?

Thanks for any hint of help :)

Comment: Do you have any code-snippet, what have you tried so far, and did you use any other hazelcast integration like spring or any other library etc.. Can you please share them also?